# Failed to resume in time - Crash

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm currently experiencing a strange exception. When I send my app to the background, open some other apps like e.g. WhatsUp and open my app again, it crashes with this [stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/brunnurs/9462978).

It happens only very seldom what makes it hard to reproduce the error.

I have no code in the AppDelegate resume method, so where does my problem come from? Could the issue be related to short memory or something like that (i'm testing on an old iPhone 4)? What would you try to catch the bug?

I read a few threads about this error-code, so I'm aware about the common problems like doing too much an the main-thread.

Thanks for all hints which could lead me to a solution!

Comment: Looks like something in Monotouch is holding up when calling the media player, can't help you out much on this, I don't use Monotouch :/

Comment: Thanks for your input David. After profiling my app with the XCode-Instruments I figured out that images in my app causes a major memory problem, which is the reason for the problem I mentioned above. So it's not really the source of the problem but only a symptom. No I need to fix my memory issue, which is not much better :-)